# Cannot get dual boot setup with Windows 10 and Kali Linux working

Tags: linux, boot, windows-10, multi-boot, kali-linux

I’m having a problem in dual boot setting on my Windows 10 machine with Kali Linux. I used this official Kali Linux guide to set things up, “[Dual Boot Kali with Windows](http://docs.kali.org/installation/dual-boot-kali-with-windows).”

My system is:

- **System:** [Lenovo Y50-70](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-y-series-laptops/y50-70-notebook-lenovo)
- **RAM:** 8GB RAM
- **Storage:** 1TB hard disk drive and a 25GB SSD
- **GPU:** [NVIDIA 860M](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-860m)
- **CPU:** Intel Core i7

First I created a 150GB partition in Windows disk management. Then I followed the steps as followed. Once the installation finished, I rebooted into Windows. I have checked BIOS and it uses the Windows Boot Manager, so I booted off the hard drive in the <kbd>F12</kbd> menu.

I got to the GRUB boot loader, and could load up Kali, but cannot for Windows. If I chose to boot with the  Windows Boot Manager, it would boot into Windows 10. Can somebody help me with this?

And another problem, my BIOS keeps freezing; I will see if I can fix this later.

I would like to have a simple dual boot menu with Kali Linux and Windows, right from the start.

Comment: So GRUB has no Windows option and Windows Boot Manager has no Kali Linux option?

Comment: If you want both to appear on the Windows Boot Manager, then I would recommend EasyBCD, although I am not completely sure it is compatible with Windows 10.

Comment: @JohnDoe the grub loader has a linux option, and windows option. Whenever I try to windows option(it appears as windowns 8) it gives me an error about not being able to load up or something...

Comment: @JohnDoe i may be able to fix the bios problem with removing the battery and putting it back in, but I need to concentrate on getting kali linux and windows in a menu first, then have the windows boot manager 2nd priority...

Comment: @JakeGould thanks for editing this, I couldn't have done it with my pc at the time.

Comment: Try doing "sudo update-grub" in the terminal. Then reboot and see if the Windows option works.

Comment: Is disk GPT style or MBR style ?

Comment: I believe it is GPT